# Using file redirects to input a variable search pattern to awk

Tags: awk

I'm attempting to write a small script in bash. The script's purpose is to pull out a search pattern from file1.txt and to print the line number of the matching search from file2.txt. I know the exact place of the pattern that I want in file1.txt, and I can pull that out quite easily with sed and awk e.g.

```
sed -n 3p file1.txt | awk '{print $4}'
```

The part that I'm having trouble with is passing that information again to awk to use as a search pattern in file2.txt. Something along the lines of:

```
awk '/search_pattern/{print NR}' file2.txt
```

I was able to get this code working in two lines of code by storing the output of the first line as a variable, and passing that variable to awk in the second line,

```
myVariable=`sed -n 3p file1.txt | awk '{print $4}'`
awk '/'"$myVariable"'/{print NR}' file2.txt
```

but this seems "inelegant". I was hoping there was a way to do this in one line of code using file redirects (or something similar?). Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide example `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` together with the output you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid `sed | awk` with

```
awk 'NR==3{print $4; exit 0}' file1.txt
```

You can do your search with:

```
search=$(awk 'NR==3{print $4; exit 0}' file1.txt)
awk -v search="$search" '$0 ~ search { print NR }' file2.txt
```

You could even write that all on one line, but I don't recommend that; clarity is more important than brevity.

In principle, you could use:

```
awk 'NR==3{search = $4; next} FNR!=NR && $0 ~ search {print NR}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

This scans `file1.txt` and finds the search pattern; then it scans `file2.txt` and finds the lines that match.  One line — even moderately clear.  There'll be lots of matches if there isn't a column 4 on line 3 of `file1.txt`.

Comment: Great, thank you so much! Let's say I wanted to use this from the command line instead of in my script. Would it look something along the lines of:

`awk -v search=$(awk 'NR==3{print $4}' file1.txt) '$0 ~ search {print NR}' file2.txt`

Comment: The use from the command line would look the same as the use in a script.  Yes, your one-liner would be a correct way to incorporate the first `awk` into the command line of the second.  You'd write the one or two lines verbatim — or adjusting the constants (3, 4) as needed.  I think the last alternative is better though.  Using one command without major contortions instead of two or three is generally better.